# Efficient solutions to general Bézout’s identity $a_1 b_1 + \dots + a_n b_n = 1$

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, diophantine-equations, integer-programming

Suppose I have integers $a_1, \dots, a_n$ which are coprime, meaning that

$$a_1 b_1 + \dots + a_n b_n = 1$$

has a solution in integers $b_1, \dots, b_n$.

I would like to get a bound saying something like:

There exists a solution with $\sum_i |b_i| < \sum_i |a_i|$

(except in the degenerate case where $a_j = 1$, $a_i = 0$ for $i \neq j$)

Presumably such things (and probably much stronger bounds) are known. Does anyone know a reference for these kinds of results?

Comment: Not an answer, but this reminded me of [Siegel's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siegel%27s_lemma).

Comment: You should be careful to distinguish coprime from mutually coprime (so that three numbers may be coprime without any two being coprime = two being mutually coprime). By doing something similar to row reduction, you should be able to come up with such a bound. Gerhard "Considering A Proof By Induction" Paseman, 2019.03.19.

Comment: Using the argument in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2436387/upper-bound-on-frobenius-coin-problem, you can find a solution where $\sum_i|a_ib_i|$ is bounded by roughly $\frac12\bigl(\max_i|a_i|\bigr)^2$.

Comment: Yes, you can guarantee a solution with $\sum|b_i|<\sum|a_i|$: https://mathoverflow.net/a/108723/9924

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Estimates for Bezout coefficients](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/108601/estimates-for-bezout-coefficients)